# Error on android with different costum button

Tags: android

i have a error on my android project that i cant solve.

I have a game menu layout in one xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RootView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gamemenu_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gaveup_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gaveup_button">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_a_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/choice_a_button">   

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_b_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/choice_b_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So for each button i have an xml and an image in folder drawable:

choice_a_button_xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/choice_a_button"></item>
</selector>
```

choice_b_button_xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/choice_b_button"></item>
</selector>
```

In layout manager of eclipse de layout are good but when i run the app on a virtual device i have an error and app not start:

```
05-15 01:22:52.284: D/dalvikvm(341): GC freed 605 objects / 48664 bytes in 166ms
05-15 01:22:52.446: D/dalvikvm(341): GC freed 59 objects / 2304 bytes in 46ms
05-15 01:22:52.814: D/dalvikvm(341): GC freed 138 objects / 6344 bytes in 42ms
05-15 01:22:53.124: D/dalvikvm(341): GC freed 48 objects / 1864 bytes in 44ms
05-15 01:22:53.724: E/dalvikvm-heap(341): 3686400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
05-15 01:22:53.724: E/(341): VM won't let us allocate 3686400 bytes
05-15 01:22:53.724: D/skia(341): --- decoder->decode returned false
05-15 01:22:53.735: D/AndroidRuntime(341): Shutting down VM
05-15 01:22:53.735: W/dalvikvm(341): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-15 01:22:53.735: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sal.app/sal.app.SALActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at sal.app.SALActivity.onCreate(SALActivity.java:23)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 22 more
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:447)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:326)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:69)
05-15 01:22:53.754: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 26 more
05-15 01:22:53.774: I/dalvikvm(341): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-15 01:22:53.774: E/dalvikvm(341): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Whats happen there? This error only ocurre in virtual devices with large screens.

This app work if i set Max VM application heap size of my virtual device to 48. But this is too much..There is any way to put program consumes less memory?

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Michaeldcooney said and you should also check for memory leaks. Also, what's the VM memory size (that's the size of memory usable by an application, not the device total memory size) for your virtual devices?

Comment: The VM Memory size actualy is 24 and dont work. But if i put 48 thats work.

Comment: There are a few possible reasons, you are holding onto Objects that you don't really need at the moment(don't put any Drawables into a static variable, for example, would lead to the whole Activity instance to be retained). Check your code; 2. you have memory leaks, use memory profiler for this; 3. You simply uses to many bitmaps, reduce their number or/and their size.

Answer (score 0):

I think the crash is due to the line that says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

You probably need to scale down your images.